# Help with Geocoding and Openlayers missing markers

Tags: 6, javascript, location

I have followed this tutorial exactly http://drupal.org/node/1002852 to create a node type with geocoding. I have a default install of [openlayers](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers), [openlayers_geocoder](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers_geocoder). Geocoding appears to be working when editing/saving the node, however the marker (or polygons) do not appear on the node's map.

Comment: Did you try using Open Street Map instead of Google Maps and if it uses v2 API of Google Maps it will require an API key.

Comment: yes. I am using open street map. (using everything that comes default after installing the modules). Since I haven't set anything, I am thinking there must be a setting i am missing. I have gone through everything.

Comment: Am I missing something? Question is tagged `7` but there is no Drupal 7 release for openlayers_geocoder.  Are you in fact using Drupal 7?

Comment: I believe he meant http://drupal.org/project/geocode, which has a Github repository with a drupal 7 version. Or maybe even http://drupal.org/project/geofield, which has to be used too, if one is going to use geocode.

Comment: somehow this got retagged with Drupal 7. It is fact Drupal 6 that I am having issues with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have gone through this same problem.

I believe this is happening to you, because you did not set the Openlayers Data Overlay on Views.

[image: Data Overlay]

And if you did, you did not selected/activated it on your Openlayers preset:

[image: Openlayers PRESET]

And if you did, you did not map the fields on the openlayers data overlay display settings:

[image: Format settings]

Comment: The issue is not with the views, but rather the map on the node itself.

Comment: Yes, but in order to display the map on the node, you have to set an Openlayers Data Overlay within Views. This is mandatory.

Comment: with d6, there aren't any default views to modify?

Comment: Not that I know of. You have to build everything for yourself. Try following EVERYTHING here: http://drupal.org/node/627816

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well, but in my case it was that I didn't have the proj4JS library downloaded. I ran drush dl-proj4js, cleared caches, and all worked as expected.